# My <style> tag is not applied in my Svelte component

Tags: css, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I am building an application using Sveltekit, and I cannot find out why my inline CSS is not applied.
I have a global CSS file loaded in my app.html which works perfectly.

Here is the component's file:

```html
<script>
    export let name;
    export let summonerLevel;
    export let profileIconId;
    export let id;

    $: imgUrl = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/13.15.1/img/profileicon/" + profileIconId + ".png"
</script>

<div class="data-user">
    <h2>Summoner Data:</h2>
    <img src={imgUrl} alt="profile icon" />
    <p> Name: {name} </p>
    <p> Level: {summonerLevel} </p>
    <p> Id: {id}</p>
</div>

<style>
    img {
        width: 6rem;
        border: solid .5rem #FFA559;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    p {
        color: black;
    }
</style>
```

I tried removing the whole global CSS file, thinking there could be conflicts and overwritten properties, but nothing changed.

I then tried to move the inline properties inside my global stylesheet, and it worked perfectly. It's just not loaded when written in a `<style>` tag.

- [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqA9R.png) is the result when I style it in the CSS file;
- [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVJr0.png) is the result when I style it in a `<style>` tag.

**Edit:** The styling works when building the app but not in the developer build.

Comment: Does the server console show errors/warnings? Is it the same for the dev server and an actual build (with preview)?

Comment: I didn't think building the actual app and it does work in the preview. It is weird however that such a feature is not available on the dev server. Also no errors are shown. Thanks for your help

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: "It is weird however that such a feature is not available on the dev server." It ***is*** available, something is just broken on your end. You could try to create a new project from scratch (`npm create svelte@latest`) to see if it works there. If so, something is off in your current project.

Comment: Have you tried importing global css in +layout.svelte (like this `import "./global.css"`) instead of app.html. Or add your CSS to `svelte:head`.